# Any way for a function to return an execution policy?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17, c++20, std

I have recently been working on a project and I have encountered a problem where I didn't wanna use the *std::execution::par* on small vectors as that would create overhead.

Well theoretically that could be solved by the function that returns either *std::execution::par* or *std::execution::seq* depending on the total size of the vector multiplied to the size of each element and compare that to a fixed value. But the problem being is that they are of different types meaning that they could not be returned. We could also just return a bool whether going parallel would be worth it but that would lead ot nasty branching and I don't want that.
I was just wondering whether ther was a way that I could neatly fix this problem

Comment: The implementation will be smart enough to not fire up a bunch of threads for small sequences.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Wouldn't the decision to parallelize need to know how expensive the individual tasks are?

Comment: If your return type is a variant of two types that depends on a runtime parameter (the size of the vector), you could use `std::variant`.

Comment: Please remove the C++11 and C++14 tags. AFAIK execution policies are C++17 minimum.

Comment: @BenVoigt — yes, bigger individual tasks could benefit from a lower threshold. The implementation can’t know the size of the task, so there’s a legitimate issue there.

Comment: Hello guys. I will remove the c++11 and c++14 tags. And no I wouldn't wanna use std::variant as this negates the point of convenicence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, they made those types distinct; presumably with the intention of avoiding this kind of runtime decision making. It will result in significant code-bloat at the very least since now every algorithm has to be instantiated. But if you think it is necessary, this is the shortest I could come up with:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <thread>
#include <variant>

using execution_variant = std::variant<
        std::execution::sequenced_policy, std::execution::parallel_policy>;

execution_variant select_execution(std::size_t items)
{
    if(items > std::thread::hardware_concurrency() * 16)
        return std::execution::par;
    return std::execution::seq;
}

void sort(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    std::visit([&](auto policy) {
            std::sort(policy, vec.begin(), vec.end()); },
        select_execution(vec.size()));
}
```

Or with a helper to make the call-site more concise:

```cpp
struct Execution
{
    execution_variant var;

    template<class Fun>
    auto operator()(Fun&& fun) const
    { return std::visit(fun, var); }

    static Execution select(std::size_t items)
    {
        if(items > std::thread::hardware_concurrency() * 16)
            return {std::execution::par};
        return {std::execution::seq};
    }
};
void sort(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    Execution::select(vec.size())([&](auto policy) {
          std::sort(policy, vec.begin(), vec.end()); });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this flexible with all of the STL's algorithms not just std::sort?

Comment: @BahramGozalov just replace the content of that lambda

Comment: Sounds good to me